# Get Request/Model Body in ASP.NET Core Exception Filter without Replay

Tags: asp.net-core, exception

I have a several models that share an interface, it looks like

```
public interface IRequest {
    public string RequestId { get; set; }
}
```

An example of a model that implements this look like

```
public class CatRequest : IRequest {
    public string RequestId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

I have a `CatController` that looks like

```
public class CatController: ControllerBase {
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddCat([FromBody] cat) {
        // call database and add cat to db
    }
}
```

Knowing fully well that several things can go wrong in the database operation, I have a global exception filter that works and it looks like

```
public void OnException(ExceptionContext context) {
    // create a proper error response message
    var error = new ErrorResponse() {
        ResponseCode = 400,
        RequestId = 2, // HERE IS THE SPOT, I WANT TO READ RequestId from the RequestBody or Model without re-reading the request

        // The solution below works, but only when it is a custom exception where I had previously manually added the Data entry
        // RequestId = context.Exception.Data["RequestId"]?.ToString()
    };
    context.Result = new JsonResult(error);
}
```

Can I get a better implementation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to handle exceptions that occur within your controller actions, using an exception filter to achieve it is ok.

Besides, you can also use middleware for global error handling.

For more information about "Handle errors in ASP.NET Core", please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#exception-filters